# Imported Sequelize connection works properly in one file but not another

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am writing a NodeJS API with express that uses Sequelize as an ORM to connect to a postgres database.

I have several API files containing the endpoint functions for each model, and I group related functions in these files.

In these files, I load the db connection by requiring the `models` folder, which contains all the model definitions, and an index file that instantiates & exports the database connection with the models.

I instantiate this at the top of any file that needs access to the database. My problem is that when I enter an endpoint, I can access the database connection perfectly. But when I call any function from another file that also accesses the database, all of my models from the `required` file are `undefined`, and it throws an error.

```js
/* api/fooApi.js */
const db = require('../models')
const logApi = require('../logApi')

async function createFoo(req, res, next) {
  try {
    // db.foo and db.log are defined here, and accessible
    const foo = await db.foo.create(req.body)
    const log = await logApi.logCreation('foo', foo)
  }
}

module.exports = { createFoo }

/* api/logApi.js */
const db = require('../models')

async function logCreation(recordType, record) {
  // db.foo and db.log are not defined here when the function is called from fooApi.js
  const log = await db.log.create({
    event: 'create',
    type: recordType,
    details: `${recordType} record created by user ${record.createdBy}`
  })
  return log
}

module.exports = { logCreation }
```

When I enter the endpoint function `createFoo()`, I have full access to everything that I expect to be in `db`, including `db.foo.create()`. But in `logCreation()`, I cannot access these same functions.

Many different models will access the `logCreation` function, so it needs to be defined in one place. The `require` statement at the top of the file is exactly the same as that in `fooApi`, but when I debug the function, `db` is an empty object without any of the properties it should have.

If I pass db as an argument to `logCreation`, then the function works, but I'd like to avoid this if I can, as it would involve a major restructuring.
Previously to having thing set up this way, I had the following in each api file:

```js
let db = null
function init (dbConn) {
  db = dbConn
}
```

At setup, I would call init() in every API file using the same instance as the argument. However, this was a super clunky way of doing things that I wanted to move away from.

So my question is: What is the correct way to set up Sequelize so that I can access the database across multiple files?
I am using implicit transactions using namespace and `cls-hooked` as directed in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem - this had nothing to do with how I was importing the file, and was entirely due to a circular dependency because a helper function on one of the models was accessing a helper function in an API file.